# Cipher String Syntax in nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

In an nginx configuration file, you might configure a list of SSL ciphers like this

```
ssl_ciphers                HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!ADH:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS;
```

What's the syntax of this cipher string?  That is, I know (or think I know, correct me if I'm wrong) that this string is meant to provide a list of possible SSL ciphers, as well as provide a priority for them.  What [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) is less great at is explaining the format of this string.

Specific questions

- Is the `!` a negation?  That is, does `!DSS` means don't use DSS?  Or is `!DSS` the same of a cipher?
- Are the `:` characters separators? That is is teh above a list of ciphers "HIGH, !aNULL, !eNULL, etc...", or does the `:` mean something else
- Are `HIGH` and `LOW` the same of ciphers, or are they special meta-directives of some kind
- Not pictured above, but [I've seen](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54639/nginx-recommended-ssl-ciphers-for-security-compatibility-with-pfs) strings like this `AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:`. Are the `-` characters part of the cipher name, or do they have a special meaning?

Is there a resource that explains how this string works, or is this a case where the people expected to work with the string are also expected to read the nginx source to figure out how it works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This syntax is from OpenSSL. See [CIPHER LIST FORMAT](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-ciphers.html#CIPHER-LIST-FORMAT).

Further down it lists different ciphers and these meta ciphers like `HIGH`

Excerpt:

> The cipher list consists of one or more cipher strings separated by
>   colons. Commas or spaces are also acceptable separators but colons are
>   normally used.
>
> The actual cipher string can take several different forms.
>
> It can consist of a single cipher suite such as RC4-SHA.
>
> It can represent a list of cipher suites containing a certain
>   algorithm, or cipher suites of a certain type. For example SHA1
>   represents all ciphers suites using the digest algorithm SHA1 and
>   SSLv3 represents all SSL v3 algorithms.
>
> Lists of cipher suites can be combined in a single cipher string using
>   the + character. This is used as a logical and operation. For example
>   SHA1+DES represents all cipher suites containing the SHA1 and the DES
>   algorithms.
>
> Each cipher string can be optionally preceded by the characters !, -
>   or +.
>
> If ! is used then the ciphers are permanently deleted from the list.
>   The ciphers deleted can never reappear in the list even if they are
>   explicitly stated.
>
> If - is used then the ciphers are deleted from the list, but some or
>   all of the ciphers can be added again by later options.
>
> If + is used then the ciphers are moved to the end of the list. This
>   option doesn't add any new ciphers it just moves matching existing
>   ones.
>
> ...

Answer (score 5):

Nginx `ssl_ciphers` directive is using [OpenSSL cipher list format](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ciphers.html).

This **cipher list** is described as one or more **cipher strings** usually **separated by colons or commas** (spaces are also supported by OpenSSL but you will have to wrap the list in quotes with nginx).

A cipher string is **a particular cipher suite or cipher suites grouped under a keyword**.

By default OpenSSL comes with a default cipher list determined at the library compilation time and that exclude ciphers suites without encryption or authentication for obvious security purposes. It should be `ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL` as for OpenSSL 1.0.

For example cipher string `HIGH` means all the cipher suites providing encryption with keys larger than 128 bits while cipher string `LOW` matches cipher suites using 56 or 64 bits keys. Also, `AES256-GCM-SHA384` and `ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA` are particular cipher suites.

Symbol `!` means to remove the group of cipher suites or the particular cipher suite when the server exchanges supported cipher suites with the client during the handshake stage. For instance `!eNULL` and `!aNULL` means remove cipher suites not providing encryption and authentication.